# Reading contents of file

Tags: python

I am trying to read text from a file and display it, yet it doesn't work.  I get either a blank result, or I get

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
```

Code

```
text1 = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt', 'r')
text1.read()
```

And I have tried

```
text1 = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt', 'r')
text1.read()
print(text1)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: `text1.read()` returns what’s been read. It doesn’t turn the object into a string. That would not make sense.

Comment: `print(text1)` will tell you the details of the actual `File` object, not the insides; this is why it looks like `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>`

Comment: Poor variable names. Try f = open(....), text1 = f.read().  'f' for file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the return value of `text.read()` to a variable and print it

```
text1 = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt', 'r')
x = text1.read()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

did you try this?

```
text1 = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt', 'r')
data  = text1.read()
print data
text1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of a call to the builtin `open` is a Python object which wraps the file, not just the contents of the file.  That's what you assigned the name `text1` to.

The `read` method on a file object returns a string of some number of bytes in the file.  If you just call `text1.read()`, that will return a string object containing all of the characters from the file.

You could print the contents of the file directly from the read statement, like so:

```
print(text1.read()
```

Or if you want to do anything else with the file contents, you would be in better shape if you save them to a local variable, then print them:

```
text_from_file = text1.read()
print(text_from_file)
```

This is because `text1.read()` will read to the end of the file, after which subsequent calls of `read()` will only return the empty string, unless you tell the file object to start again from the beginning of the file (by calling `text1.seek(0)`).

The call that you made in your second example, `print(text1)`, prints the representation of the object called text1.  In Python 2, that looks like this:

```
Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 10:15:50) 
>>> foo = open('.bash_history', 'r')
>>> print(foo)
<open file '.bash_history', mode 'r' at 0xbb440>
>>>
```

In Python3, the object is different so the representation is different:

```
Python 3.3.1 (v3.3.1:d9893d13c628, Apr  6 2013, 10:32:10)
>>> foo = open('.bash_history', 'r')
>>> print(foo)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='.bash_history' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>>
```

Either way, you asked it to print the representation of the Python object, rather than the contents of the file to which the object gives you Pythonic access.

Answer (score 0):

try `print text1.read()` to get it to work